# Send ajax error to client issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I am building an app in node and I'm working on the error handling aspect. I am using ajax to post data from a form to my server to be uploaded into my postgresql database. One of the constraints is the email has to be unique, otherwise it will throw an error. I was able to print the error on the server side console, but I want the error to also console.log and/or alert on the client's browser as well. Here is what I have tried:

Client side:

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var data = {
        first_name: $("#firstName").val(),
        last_name: $("#lastName").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        password: $("#password").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/add",
        data: data,
        success: function() {
            console.log('success');
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('some error');
        }
    });
});
```

Server side:

```
router.route('/add').post(function(req, res) {                         
    knex('users').insert({
        first_name: req.body.first_name, 
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password
    }).then().catch(function(error){
        console.log("ERROR ERRROR ERROR " + error) //prints on console 
        res.send(error);
    });
});
```

With this code, the problem is the error function is not being called on the client side... Can someone help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is exactly what the `success` and `error` in the ajax for. You can use that to send success or error status code. For example: `res.send(400)` or `res.send(200)`.

You can also send data with the response, for example `res.send(400, data)`

Of course you can use any other HTTP codes as you find convenient.

Now, in the

```
error: function(data)) {
   alert('some error');
}
```

the alert should be triggered